# How to stop the Crawler

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to write a crawler that goes to a website and searches for a list of keywords, with max_Depth of 2. But the **scraper** is supposed to stop once any of the keyword's appears on any page, the problem i am facing right now is that the crawler does-not stop when it first see's any of the keywords.

Even after trying, early return command, break command and CloseSpider Commands and even python exit commands.

My class of the Crawler:

```
class WebsiteSpider(CrawlSpider):

name = "webcrawler"

allowed_domains = ["www.roomtoread.org"]
start_urls = ["https://"+"www.roomtoread.org"]
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback="check_buzzwords")]

crawl_count = 0
words_found = 0                                 

def check_buzzwords(self, response):

    self.__class__.crawl_count += 1

    crawl_count = self.__class__.crawl_count

    wordlist = [
        "sfdc",
        "pardot",
        "Web-to-Lead",
        "salesforce"
        ]

    url = response.url
    contenttype = response.headers.get("content-type", "").decode('utf-8').lower()
    data = response.body.decode('utf-8')

    for word in wordlist:
            substrings = find_all_substrings(data, word)
            for pos in substrings:
                    ok = False
                    if not ok:
                        if  self.__class__.words_found==0:
                            self.__class__.words_found += 1
                            print(word + "," + url + ";")
                            STOP!

                            
                            
                        
    return Item()

def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
    if getattr(response, "encoding", None) != None:
            return CrawlSpider._requests_to_follow(self, response)
    else:
            return []
```

I want it to stop execution when `if not ok:` is `True`.

Comment: can you show the settings of spider?

Answer (score 1):

When I want to stop a spider, I usually use the exception `exception scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider(reason='cancelled')` from [Scrapy-Docs](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html?highlight=closeSpider).

The example there shows how you **can** use it:

```
if 'Bandwidth exceeded' in response.body:
    raise CloseSpider('bandwidth_exceeded')
```

In your case something like

```
if not ok:
    raise CloseSpider('keyword_found')
```

Or is that what you meant with

> CloseSpider Commands

and already tried it?